# How to return user back to the page where he came from, after successful logout?

Tags: php, session, cookies, logout

How to return user back to the page where he came from, after successful logout? 
My logout function looks like that.

```
function logout()
{
global $db;
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['id']) || isset($_COOKIE['id'])) {
$db->query("update `users` 
            set `ckey`= '', `ctime`= '' 
            where `id`='$_SESSION[id]' OR  `id` = '$_COOKIE[id]'") or die($db->error);
}           

/************ Delete the sessions****************/
unset($_SESSION['id']);
unset($_SESSION['login']);
unset($_SESSION['level']);
unset($_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
session_unset();
session_destroy(); 

/* Delete the cookies*******************/
setcookie("id", '', time()-60*60*24*COOKIE_TIME_OUT, "/");
setcookie("login", '', time()-60*60*24*COOKIE_TIME_OUT, "/");
setcookie("key", '', time()-60*60*24*COOKIE_TIME_OUT, "/");

header("Location: ????");
}
```

Comment: Couldn't you just send `history.go(-2)` with javascript?

Comment: How to detect index page's url with php?

Comment: All "can you edit my code please?" considered to be "too localized" questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not perfect but you can use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` to get the page URI from where the user clicked on the "logout" link.

Comment: How to detect index page's url with php?

Comment: What do you mean by the "index page"?

Comment: detecting websites url with php

Answer (score 1):

When you load all your views you can append the current URL to the logout link

```
logout.php?return=/page/param
```

Then when you logout, you can check `$_GET['return']` and redirect there.

You could fall back on `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` (because it can be edited), and finally on failure just redirect to your home page.